# Azure Function - Redirect with querystring

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have a json object that I want to pass as querystring with redirect. The following code works.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.res = {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            'Location': 'https://www.stackoverflow.com?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3'
        }
        body: 'Redirecting...'
    };
    context.done();
};
```

There are Node packages that can convert my json to a querystring. However, I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it, something like below. Similar to how we get the querystring in request.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.res = {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            'Location': 'https://www.stackoverflow.com?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3'
        },
        query:{
            var4: 4,
            var5: 5,
            var6: 6
        },
        body: 'Redirecting...'
    };
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no value like `query` on the Azure Functions Node [response object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#response-object). If you desire something like this to be integrated into Azure Functions, you can make a feature request for the node worker [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues), or even open a PR yourself to add that functionality. Note that the developer team may decide that the feature does not warrant the extra cost of maintenance.